# Python 2.7 - Using column from CSV as variables in a for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I'm trying to pull in a md5 hash stored in a csv for members on a mailchimp list, so I can use their GET members goals function for all members in a segment at once.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

```
import csv 
from mailchimp3 import MailChimp

csvFileName = "responseid.csv" 

client = MailChimp('', '') 

def subscriber_hash(subscriber_hash): 
    client.lists.members.goals.all(list_id='', subscriber_hash='subscriber_hash')


with open(csvFileName, 'r') as csvfile:
    contact_reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in contact_reader:
        subscriber_hash(row["id"])
```

---

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What's the error that you are getting with code? Please edit the question to mention the error trace

Comment: You are setting the variable `subscriber_hash` to the string value `'subscriber_hash'` and you are completely ignoring the input variable `subscriber_hash`